# Do Red Squadron fighters appear on screen in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I've found numerous references on the internet that Red Squadron were an actual unit in the battle of Starkiller base ([plenty of references can be found here, with further citation and references](http://www.starwars.com/news/its-the-resistance)). So I know at least they canonically  exist and participated. However. Are their fighters (as in the red markings) ever shown on screen (either in battle or on the ground) or do you just see Blue Squadron?

(Alternatively are they just denoted with the same blue markings? (both in and out of universe explanations appreciated if this is the case!))

Comment: Please accept an answer, or highlight additional information you're looking for.

Comment: @theMaestro73 your answer doesn't answer my question I'm afraid. I've edited the body for clarification (the title remained correct)

Answer (score 2):

They are shown on screen. According to *Poe Dameron: Flight log*, Nien Nunb is Red 3, and appears at one point in the battle. Several other Red Squadron pilots are pictured as well. The exterior markings on the fighters may not differentiate as much.

[image: Poe Dameron: Flight Log]

[image: Nien Nunb in the Battle of Starkiller Base]